# How to include CSS style inside HTML style (code generated via ASP.Net MVC Razor page)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, styles, razor-pages

I'm still at my early beginning with ASP.Net MVC. So, I'm not sure if I'm following good practices or not.

I want to generate HTML code based on CSS style

Razor page:

```
@foreach (p in ...)
{
    <td style="@Helper.CustomBackground(p) @Helper.CustomComplexStyle(p)">...</td>
}
```

CSS classes:

```
.complexStyleA {
   // ...
}

.complexStyleB { }
```

C# helper method:

```
// None of the styling method has the "style" attribute, so I can concatenate several custom-styles
public static class Helper
{
    // Basic direct styling
    public static string CustomBackground(object p) => "{ background: red; }";
    
    // More complex styling based on CSS ones
    public static string CustomComplexStyle(object p) => "{ // complexStyleA, complexStyleB, etc. based on p; }"
}
```

I don't really mind generated all the code inside the HTML tags, but generate a table with several thousand lines and can obviously reduce the file size!

Thanks for any insights :-)

**UPDATE**

I think that I will do something as follow :

```
<td @Html.Raw(@Hepers.ConcatenateCSSClasses(@CustomComplexStyle(p),
                                            @OtherCustomComplexStyle(p),
                                            ...))>
    ...
</td>
```

where `@concatenateCSSClasses()` removes all `" class="` ans `@...Syle(p)` returns `"class=\"...StyleXYZ\""`, unless I can have duplicated tag attributes.. Any better ideas?

**UPDATE with cleaner methods**

```
public static string HTMLTagAttribute(FieldType fieldType, Field field = null)
{
    string output = "";

    // Makes distinction between hearder and body
    if (field == null)
    {
        output += HTMLHeaderTagClassAttributes(fieldType);
        output += HTMLHeaderTagStyleAttributes(fieldType);
    }
    else
    {
        output += HTMLBodyTagClassAttributes(fieldType, field);
        output += HTMLBodyTagStyleAttributes(fieldType, field);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Body only shown with clear distinction between classes and (inline styles). I don't detail the samll method `HTMLWidth()`, `HTMLBackground()`, etc. which are self explanatory.

```
#region HTML Body Tag Attribute Methods

private static string HTMLBodyTagStyleAttributes(FieldType fieldType, Field field)
{
    AttributeValues style = new AttributeValues("style");

    style += HTMLWidth(fieldType);
    style += HTMLBackground(fieldType, field);
    style += HTMLAlign(fieldType);

    return style.ToString();
}

private static string HTMLBodyTagClassAttributes(FieldType fieldType, Field field)
{
    AttributeValues cls = new AttributeValues("class");

    cls += HTMLTopBorder(fieldType, field);
    cls += HTMLSideBorder(fieldType);

    return cls.ToString();
}

#endregion
```

Class which helps concatenate class and style attribute values (with no extra space).

```
/// <summary>Class to help format HMTL class and style attribute values</summary>
class AttributeValues
{
    private readonly string _attribute = "";
    private readonly List<string> _values = new List<string>();

    // TODO - Make distinction bewteen class and styles        
    #region Constructors

    public AttributeValues(string attribute)
    {
        _attribute = attribute;
    }

    #endregion

    public static AttributeValues operator +(AttributeValues values, string value)
    {
        if (value != "") values._values.Add(value);

        return values;
    }
    
    public static bool operator ==(AttributeValues values, string value) => values == value;

    public static bool operator !=(AttributeValues values, string value) => values != value;
    
    #region Public Overridden Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string values = "";

        foreach (string value in _values)
        {
            if (values != "") values += " ";

            values += value;
        }

        return values != "" ? $"{ _attribute }=\"{ values }\"" :"" ;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => base.Equals(obj);
    
    public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
    
    #endregion
}
```

And finally in the Razor page (apparently, I have to wrap it in `HTML.Raw()` because of the `"` (I agree that it could be refractor within the `th`, but doesn't make the code easier):

```
<td Html.Raw(Helpers.HTMLTagAttribute(Enums.FieldType.Account))>..</td>
```

Comment: In my opinion what you are doing is not standard... the best practice is to put your styles in a `.css` file and include that file... if you want more flexibility then you can use `.less` or `.sass` to generate your `.css`... using inline style (the way you are including inline style in your `td`) is not best practice... also I think writing an HTML Helper to include style is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think that for now own, I will stil with one `Helpers.HTMLTagAttribute()` method and split it to serveral private ones to return class and style for each row. Of course, I'll try to gather much as possible in CSS classes, but the problem is that I color some cells based on a numerical value, so I'm not going to create `256^4` classes (including transparency). But, I agree that SASS or LESS (which I don't really know) will help me at some point.

Comment: I misunderstood your question... (in the question your are returning a static style `{ background: red; }`) but your explanation made it clear that you using p to build a dynamic style... in your scenario you can use the solution that you are using... you don't have to use TagBuilder... you can also write a static method to build your dynamic style... but I think you are on the right path

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned a bit my code , but the problem is that I end up with a HTML file which exceeds 20 Mb and will probably still grow. See update, even if they are still room for improvement..